# Get modal to fire from parent component

Tags: reactjs

Noob question here. How do I fire the toggle component of the Modal from the parent component? I want the modal to open when the button is clicked on the parent component. The button will submit a form and once the form has been submitted I want the modal to fire. I'm trying to get it to fire in `function handleSubmit(e)`

Child Component: `Modal.jsx`

```
class ModalExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      modal: !prevState.modal
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Path: `Parent.jsx`

```
export default function ForgotPassword() {
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <div className="container h-100">
      <ModalExample toggle />
      <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Open modal</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you need to use  refs

Comment: Can you please show me what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use refs as follows

```
export default function ForgotPassword() {
      function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }

      return (
        <div className="container h-100">
          <ModalExample  ref={instance => { this.child = instance; }}  />
          <button onClick={() => { this.child.toggle(); }}>Open modal</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways, but the way I've done it is by **pulling the toggle function to the parent class and passing both the function and the state value to the modal in props**.

You can then call that props function in your modal to toggle its display, although this will turn your pure component into a stateful component.

Child Component: `Modal.jsx`

```
class ModalExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal isOpen={this.props.modal} toggle={this.props.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.props.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Parent: `Parent.jsx`

```
class ForgotPassword() extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false
    };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      modal: !prevState.modal
    }));
  }

  return (
    <div className="container h-100">
      <ModalExample toggle={this.toggle} modal={this.state.modal} />
      <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Open modal</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've thought about doing that. It just seems repetitive. If I'm using the model in multiple places, I assume it's better to keep the logic for the model in the modal component.

Comment: Yep, Jibin's answer looks cleaner as well, I would accept his.